# get data from json with layers in objective c

Tags: objective-c, json

i am using twiiter api,trying to get a url from a json.

the url is at "media_url" but its deep inside the json. how do i get inside the json and pull the "media_url" out?
(the path to "media_url" is entities->media[8]-->media_url)

i succeded in geting the "text" because its in high level like entities with:
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *text;
but if i try
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSURL *media_url;
i get nil

this is an example from the json:

```
2017-04-05 12:46:18.272 interview[11043:762614] tweet: {
    contributors = "<null>";
    coordinates = "<null>";
    "created_at" = "Wed Apr 05 09:00:01 +0000 2017";
    entities =     {
        hashtags =         (
        );
        media =         (
                        {
                "display_url" = "pic.twitter.com/tWr5Y69Z3o";
                "expanded_url" = "https://twitter.com/ForbesTech/status/849547162354679808/photo/1";
                id = 849547159993274368;
                "id_str" = 849547159993274368;
                indices =                 (
                    112,
                    135
                );
                "media_url" = "http://pbs.twimg.com/media/C8oypBNXUAArlze.jpg";
```

Comment: You need to convert your JSON into a NSDictionary and then retrieve the value with something like `[[dict[@"tweet"][@"entities"][@"media"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"media_url"]`, where `0` is the index of the media.

Comment: thank you for the quick reply, this is how i retrive the data @vitormm
'-(void)getHomeTimelineWithSuccess:(void (^)(NSArray<JVITweet *> *))success failed:(void (^)(NSError *))failure {
    [self.twitter getHomeTimelineSinceID:nil count:10 successBlock:^(NSArray *statuses) {
        NSMutableArray<JVITweet *> *list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (NSDictionary *statusDict in statuses) {
            [list addObject:[[JVITweet alloc] initWithDictionary:statusDict error:nil]];'

Comment: and this is whay i tryed                                                                                             /* this is how i try to get the media url from the json
             if(statusDict[@"entities"][@"media"][@"media_url"] != nil){
            [list addObject:[[JVITweet alloc] initWithDictionary:statusDict[@"entities"][@"media"][@"media_url"] error:nil]];
            }*/

Comment: Please add the additional code to your question for better readablity.

Comment: @adambaranes try to use `if ([[statusDict[@"tweet"][@"entities"][@"media"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"media_url"] != nil){ [list addObject:[[JVITweet alloc] initWithDictionary:[[statusDict[@"tweet"][@"entities"][@"media"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"media_url"] error:nil]]; }`

Answer (score 0):

Parse your JSON into an NSObject using [NSJSONSerialization JSONObject​With​Data:​options:​error:​]. Then you will get back an object that's NSArray or NSDictionary. You can then traverse that object like so:

```
NSString *mediaUrl = [[dict[@"tweet"][@"entities"][@"media"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"media_url"]
```